# Can Solr capable of pause/resume index through API call?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Is there anything in solr support pause/resume indexing like refresh_interval in elasticsearch ? I already took a look at solr documents but couldn't find nothing. Thanks.

Comment: `refresh_interval` doesn't really pause or resume indexing, it just stops making the recently indexed documents available for searching if you set it to `-1` (unless I've misunderstood something?). `autoCommit` and  `commitWithin` will do the same thing in Solr.

Comment: why do you want to pause indexation? I was always thinking, that you could just control your post script/solrj application